# Typescript type conversion

Tags: typescript

Is it true that TypeScript allows us to override its inferred and analyzed view of types in any way we want to?

Consider the following simple example please

```
let myAge: number;
myAge = window.prompt('age?'); 
  // we cannot do this because window.prompt returns a string
  // so we need a type assertion, but the 2 ways I know does not cut it

let myAgeStr: string;
myAgeStr = window.prompt('age?'); 

// method 1
myAge = myAgeStr as number; // fails

 // method 2
myAge = <number> myAgeStr; // also fails
```

`Fails` means `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'`.

What do we do then?

Comment: can you try with `myAge = +myAgeStr;` or `myAge = parseInt(myAgeStr);`

Comment: just using standard javascript conversion.

Comment: like this fiddle https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20myAge%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Alet%20myAgeStr%3A%20string%3B%0D%0AmyAgeStr%20%3D%20window.prompt('age%3F')%3B%20%0D%0AmyAge%20%3D%20%2BmyAgeStr%3B%20%0D%0Aconsole.log(myAge)%3B

Comment: That definitely does it. Thank you. But why does typescript fail in my examples? Afer all, it is the big-brother of JS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TL;DR you can do it but you probably don't want to.  Parse the string as a number.

---

Type assertions from one type to another are only allowed when at least one of the types is assignable to the other.  There's the safe "up casting" direction, where a you widen a value to a supertype (throwing away information):

```
// safe
let h = "hello" as (string | number); // widening string to string|number
```

And there's the unsafe "down casting" direction, where you narrow a value to a subtype (*adding* information the compiler can't verify):

```
// unsafe but correct
let okay = h as "hello"; // narrowed string|number to string literal "hello"
// unsafe and incorrect
let notOkay = h as "goodbye"; // narrowed string|number to string literal "goodbye".
```

But what you can't do is do type assertions between two unrelated types, where neither one is assignable to the other:

```
let s = "string";
s as number; // error
let n = 1;
n as string; // error
```

Enter `any`, the escape hatch from the type system.  The type `any` is considered assignable to and from every other type.   If you *really* want to assert a value is an unrelated type, you can use `any` as an intermediary.  This is quite unsafe, of course:

```
n = s as any as number; // you're the boss
s = n as any as string; // you're the boss
```

So you can do it:

```
myAge = window.prompt('age?') as any as number; // bad idea
```

*But please don't do it.*  TypeScript is warning you, correctly, that a `string` is not a `number`.  Sure, lots of JavaScript functions will coerce a string to a number if that's what they expect, but lots of JavaScript functions *won't* do that:

```
n = "3" as any as number;
console.log(n + 5); // 35, not 8!
```

So it's really a bad idea to force TypeScript to allow you to do foolish things.  If you want to interpret a string as a number, *parse it*:

```
let myAge: number;
myAge = Number(window.prompt('age?')); // always a number, may be NaN
```

The `Number` function will always return a `number`, and TypeScript knows this, and now both you and TypeScript are happy, both at compile time and runtime.  Do keep in mind that `NaN` is a `number` and that's what you'll get if you do something like `Number("hello")`.  So after getting `myAge` as a `number`, you probably want to check it via `isNaN()` before doing anything numeric with it.

---

Hope that helps; good luck!